# Understanding and researching with Spectroscopy

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, spectroscopy

I am very new to physics so don't know a whole lot yet, so please correct any incorrect vocabulary you may find. Papers that are easy for beginners to understand are also very welcome!

*Context:*

- I am doing a project on spectroscopy using a phone/web camera, and a diffraction slide which I believe works kind of like a crystal. I am supposed to choose something to do this project on, one example I was given was crushing up leaves to see how much chlorophyll is in them. I've been trying to do research on what other projects I might be able to do/other things I could measure, but most of what I'm finding is too advanced for our setup.

*My understanding:*

- I have a baseline understanding that spectroscopy measures the amounts of liquids/gases (Like the amount of carbon dioxide on a planet, or the amount of salt in a solution), by measuring the amount of "light" (electromagnetic radiation not just visible light) absorbed by the said liquids/gases. I'm just not sure I'm correlating that to what types of things I can (reasonably) do.

*Question:*

**If anyone could correct my understanding or give me examples of ways Spectroscopy can be used so I can come up with similar ideas it would be much appreciated!**

Comment: Yesterday my granddaughter asked me about one of the instruments in my lab, so I showed her the titanium line from the antistatic mat on the bench using x-ray fluorescence spectroscopy.